# WriteStream.emit Error: what am i doing wrong in this code

Tags: node.js

I am learning nodeJs. I am at the point where I am learning about streams in the nodejs.
I am trying to write a file using writestream and once it is finished writing I am trying to read the same using readstream. The code of writing file works flowlessly but when I try to read the file on 'finish' event of writestream it gives me an error.
Here is my code:

```
writerstream.on('finish', function(){
    console.log('write complete');
    var readerstream = fs.ReadStream('output.txt');
    var data2 = '';
    readerStream.setEncoding('UTF8');

    readerstream.on('data', function(chunk){
        data2+=chunk;
    });

    readerstream.on('end', function(){
     console.log('Test Message');
     console.log(data2);       
    });
});
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. It will really help me in learning well.

Error:

```
ReferenceError: readerStream is not defined
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (D:\D\PV\NodeJs\Second.js:47:5)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at WriteStream.emit (events.js:208:7)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:614:14)
at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:465:3)
at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:455:7)
at fs.write (fs.js:2192:5)
at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:685:5))
```

Comment: could you provide the error?

Comment: also, in node usualli it is _fs.createReadStream_

Comment: This is the error:at WriteStream.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:614:14)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:465:3)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:455:7)
    at fs.write (fs.js:2192:5)
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:685:5)

Comment: Added, fs.createReadStream, still the same error

Comment: It seems like the first few lines of the error are still missing.  Mind including them?

Comment: Added, extra error.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo.  readStream vs readstream

Comment: Thanks, @ctt that seems to solve the error.